# JS undefined error when form is submited

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this form:

```
<form onsubmit="return validarIDC()">
                <div class="labelBox">
                    <div>
                        <label>Destinatario:</label>
                        <select name="destinatario">
                            <option value="hombre">Sr.</option>
                            <option value="mujer">Sra.</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Apellido y<br>nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre"> *
                    </div>
                    <div id="ubicarCampo">
                        <label>Razón Social:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="razon">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email"> *
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Teléfono:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono"> *
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Celular:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="celular">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Via de Contacto:</label>
                        <select name="via">
                            <option value="opc1">E-mail</option>
                            <option value="opc2">Telefono</option>
                            <option value="opc3">Correo postal</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Comentarios:</label>
                        <textarea max="300"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </div>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

and i've done a function to validate all the data from inputs, and it works perfectly exept for one error, more details after the code, here is the JS:

```
function validarIDC() {
    var errores = [];  
    var er = /^[\w]+$/;

    if (document.contactForm.nombre.value == "" || document.contactForm.nombre.value == null) {
        errores.push("El nombre es obligatorio.");
    }
    else if (!er.test(document.contactForm.nombre.value)) {
        errores.push("El nombre contiene caracteres no validos o      Espacios.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.telefono.value == "") {
        errores.push("Debe ingresar un telefono")
    }
    else if (isNaN(document.contactForm.telefono.value)) {
             errores.push("El campo telefono contiene caracteres no validos.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.email.value == "") {
        errores.push("Debe especificar una dirección de Email.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.celular.value !== "" &&                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 isNaN(document.contactForm.celular.value)) {
        errores.push("El campo celular contiene caracteres no validos.");
    }
    if (errores.length > 0) {
        msg = alert("Error/es: \n");
        for (var i = 0; i < errores.length; i++) {
            msg += errores[i] + "\n";
        }
        alert(msg);
        return false;    
    }
    document.contactForm.submit.disable = true;
    alert("Los datos han sido enviados exitosamente!");
    return true;
}
```

So when i submit it pops the *alert(msg)* but surprisingly when any condition its true i get "undefined" sticked to a side of the errors.. the console log saids nothing and i don't know what am i doing wrong.. please can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: FYI, A textbox's value is not going to be null so those checks are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need initialize the variable, since `alert()` doesn't returns anything `msg` is `undefined`.

```
msg = "Error/es: \n";
```

instead of

```
msg = alert("Error/es: \n");
```

---

You can use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var msg = "Error/es: \n" + errores.join("\n");
```

Comment: to extend the answer: unlike `prompt()` or `confirm()`, `alert()` does not return a result, as per the specification: http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#ref-for-dom-window-alert-4

Comment: Ok thank you, that helped, and sorry for that easy question.. i clearly need to open my eyes, still don't know how i've missed that awfull syntax.. anyway thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you should specify a name and id to your form...

here is a working code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return validarIDC()" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                <div class="labelBox">
                    <div>
                        <label>Destinatario:</label>
                        <select name="destinatario">
                            <option value="hombre">Sr.</option>
                            <option value="mujer">Sra.</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Apellido y<br>nombre:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"> *
                    </div>
                    <div id="ubicarCampo">
                        <label>Razón Social:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="razon">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email"> *
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Teléfono:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="telefono"> *
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Celular:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="celular">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Via de Contacto:</label>
                        <select name="via">
                            <option value="opc1">E-mail</option>
                            <option value="opc2">Telefono</option>
                            <option value="opc3">Correo postal</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Comentarios:</label>
                        <textarea max="300"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </div>
            </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validarIDC() {
    var errores = [];  
    var er = /^[\w]+$/;

    if (document.contactForm.nombre.value == "" || document.contactForm.nombre.value == null) {
        errores.push("El nombre es obligatorio.");
    }
    else if (!er.test(document.contactForm.nombre.value)) {
        errores.push("El nombre contiene caracteres no validos o      Espacios.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.telefono.value == "") {
        errores.push("Debe ingresar un telefono")
    }
    else if (isNaN(document.contactForm.telefono.value)) {
             errores.push("El campo telefono contiene caracteres no validos.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.email.value == "") {
        errores.push("Debe especificar una dirección de Email.");
    }
    if (document.contactForm.celular.value !== "" &&                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 isNaN(document.contactForm.celular.value)) {
        errores.push("El campo celular contiene caracteres no validos.");
    }
    if (errores.length > 0) {
        msg = alert("Error/es: \n");
        for (var i = 0; i < errores.length; i++) {
            msg += errores[i] + "\n";
        }
        alert(msg);
        return false;    
    }
    document.contactForm.submit.disable = true;
    alert("Los datos han sido enviados exitosamente!");
    return true;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```